# Why this metadata.json is not valid

Tags: metadata

```
{
  "source": {
    "hash": "",
    "language": "Ask! 0.4.0",
    "compiler": "asc 0.19.23"
  },
  "contract": {
    "name": "",
    "version": "",
    "authors": []
  },
  "V3": {
    "spec": {
      "constructors": [
        {
          "args": [
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 1,
                "displayName": [
                  "string"
                ]
              },
              "label": "name"
            },
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 1,
                "displayName": [
                  "string"
                ]
              },
              "label": "symbol"
            }
          ],
          "docs": [],
          "label": "default",
          "payable": false,
          "selector": "0xed4b9d1b"
        }
      ],
      "messages": [
        {
          "mutates": true,
          "payable": true,
          "args": [
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "label": "to"
            },
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 4,
                "displayName": [
                  "u128"
                ]
              },
              "label": "amount"
            }
          ],
          "docs": [],
          "label": "mint",
          "selector": "0xcfdd9aa2"
        },
        {
          "mutates": true,
          "payable": true,
          "args": [
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "label": "from"
            },
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 4,
                "displayName": [
                  "u128"
                ]
              },
              "label": "amount"
            }
          ],
          "docs": [],
          "label": "burn",
          "selector": "0xb1efc17b"
        },
        {
          "mutates": false,
          "payable": false,
          "args": [],
          "returnType": {
            "type": 1,
            "displayName": [
              "string"
            ]
          },
          "docs": [],
          "label": "name",
          "selector": "0x3adaf70d"
        },
        {
          "mutates": false,
          "payable": false,
          "args": [],
          "returnType": {
            "type": 1,
            "displayName": [
              "string"
            ]
          },
          "docs": [],
          "label": "symbol",
          "selector": "0x9bd1933e"
        },
        {
          "mutates": false,
          "payable": false,
          "args": [],
          "returnType": {
            "type": 0,
            "displayName": [
              "u8"
            ]
          },
          "docs": [],
          "label": "decimal",
          "selector": "0xcc3fec6d"
        },
        {
          "mutates": false,
          "payable": false,
          "args": [],
          "returnType": {
            "type": 4,
            "displayName": [
              "u128"
            ]
          },
          "docs": [],
          "label": "totalSupply",
          "selector": "0xcae60595"
        },
        {
          "mutates": false,
          "payable": false,
          "args": [
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "label": "account"
            }
          ],
          "returnType": {
            "type": 4,
            "displayName": [
              "u128"
            ]
          },
          "docs": [],
          "label": "balanceOf",
          "selector": "0xf48def67"
        },
        {
          "mutates": true,
          "payable": true,
          "args": [
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "label": "recipient"
            },
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 4,
                "displayName": [
                  "u128"
                ]
              },
              "label": "amount"
            }
          ],
          "returnType": {
            "type": 5,
            "displayName": [
              "bool"
            ]
          },
          "docs": [],
          "label": "transfer",
          "selector": "0x84a15da1"
        },
        {
          "mutates": false,
          "payable": false,
          "args": [
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "label": "owner"
            },
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "label": "spender"
            }
          ],
          "returnType": {
            "type": 4,
            "displayName": [
              "u128"
            ]
          },
          "docs": [],
          "label": "allowance",
          "selector": "0x6a00165e"
        },
        {
          "mutates": true,
          "payable": true,
          "args": [
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "label": "spender"
            },
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 4,
                "displayName": [
                  "u128"
                ]
              },
              "label": "amount"
            }
          ],
          "returnType": {
            "type": 5,
            "displayName": [
              "bool"
            ]
          },
          "docs": [],
          "label": "approve",
          "selector": "0x681266a0"
        },
        {
          "mutates": true,
          "payable": true,
          "args": [
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "label": "sender"
            },
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "label": "recipient"
            },
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 4,
                "displayName": [
                  "u128"
                ]
              },
              "label": "amount"
            }
          ],
          "returnType": {
            "type": 5,
            "displayName": [
              "bool"
            ]
          },
          "docs": [],
          "label": "transferFrom",
          "selector": "0x02a6e0d5"
        },
        {
          "mutates": true,
          "payable": true,
          "args": [
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "label": "spender"
            },
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 4,
                "displayName": [
                  "u128"
                ]
              },
              "label": "addedValue"
            }
          ],
          "returnType": {
            "type": 5,
            "displayName": [
              "bool"
            ]
          },
          "docs": [],
          "label": "increaseAllowance",
          "selector": "0xcb005356"
        },
        {
          "mutates": true,
          "payable": true,
          "args": [
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "label": "spender"
            },
            {
              "type": {
                "type": 4,
                "displayName": [
                  "u128"
                ]
              },
              "label": "subtractedValue"
            }
          ],
          "returnType": {
            "type": 5,
            "displayName": [
              "bool"
            ]
          },
          "docs": [],
          "label": "decreaseAllowance",
          "selector": "0xe19fabb4"
        }
      ],
      "events": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "label": "Transfer",
          "args": [
            {
              "label": "from",
              "indexed": false,
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "docs": [
                ""
              ]
            },
            {
              "label": "to",
              "indexed": false,
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "docs": [
                ""
              ]
            },
            {
              "label": "value",
              "indexed": false,
              "type": {
                "type": 4,
                "displayName": [
                  "u128"
                ]
              },
              "docs": [
                ""
              ]
            }
          ],
          "docs": [
            ""
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "label": "Approval",
          "args": [
            {
              "label": "owner",
              "indexed": false,
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "docs": [
                ""
              ]
            },
            {
              "label": "spender",
              "indexed": false,
              "type": {
                "type": 3,
                "displayName": [
                  "AccountId"
                ]
              },
              "docs": [
                ""
              ]
            },
            {
              "label": "value",
              "indexed": false,
              "type": {
                "type": 4,
                "displayName": [
                  "u128"
                ]
              },
              "docs": [
                ""
              ]
            }
          ],
          "docs": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      ],
      "docs": [
        ""
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "type": {
          "def": {
            "primitive": "u8"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "type": {
          "def": {
            "primitive": "str"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "type": {
          "def": {
            "array": {
              "len": 32,
              "type": 0
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "type": {
          "def": {
            "composite": {
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "inner",
                  "type": 2,
                  "typeName": "FixedArray32<u8>"
                }
              ]
            },
            "path": []
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "type": {
          "def": {
            "primitive": "u128"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "type": {
          "def": {
            "primitive": "bool"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

it show error:

```
PortableRegistry: 3: Error extracting {"path":[],"params":[],"def":{"composite":{"fields":[{"name":"inner","type":2,"typeName":"FixedArray32<u8>","docs":[]}]}},"docs":[]}: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
```

I could not find any thing wrong with this format.

I meet this error when I update the format design to the latest V3.
I have not met this error when use old metadata format.

Answer (score 3):

I played around a bit with your example.

The JS API doesn't seem to like the fact that the `path` for the `composite` has no entries and fails on trying to extract values from that. (It uses these to create the human Java-like type names)

Adding entries to the path yields no errors.

Comment: Thx! ink metadata format has no spec, so it's so hard to align the impl details.

Comment: Also took a peek after seeing this comment... in this case the path is not strictly needed but rather used to detect special types. With this in mind, adjusted things a bit so that the JS API does handle these without failing in https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/pull/5143